# Installing Google Assistant on windows 10 got an error

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I have been installing google assistant to my windows 10 laptop, reading about it on different stackoverflow forums and on its website couldn't get it to work but then I tried this one [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7gfrKj4INk)

I got everything to work but at the end when I want to test the google assistant I get error (which I read about on here also but couldn't solve it) this is what I wrote on cmd :

`python -m googlesamples.assistant`

and this is error I got :

> C:\Users\kalle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No
>   module named googlesamples.assistant.**main**;
>   'googlesamples.assistant' is a package and cannot be directly
>   executed---

I have got Project ID and Model Id in case you ask to create.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `python -m googlesamples.assistant`. That's not a script, it's basically a directory. You probably want to run `python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk`.